# kendo pop up window input box are not allowing to select and copy text by mouse

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui in my project. I am facing issue in pop window input box. Its not allowing me to select and copy text from input boxes. Problem is only on chrome browser. Can anybody help ???

Comment: add some code (ideally a demo) and the version # of Kendo UI you're using